# Xcode 10.1 not updates from 10.0

Tags: xcode, updates, macos-mojave

I just updated to the new Mojave and trying to compile our application to my new iPhone XMax but Xcode tells me:

> **Could not locate device support files.**
>   This iPhone XS Max is running iOS 12.1 (16B92), which may not be supported by this version of Xcode.

[image]

After I checked the about sections of Xcode it shows that the version is: Version 10.0 (10A255).

If I'm checking the App Store it shows that the 10.1 is already out, but I cannot update. All buttons shows just the "open" not the "update". Cannot find any solution. How could it happens?

Comment: I haven't heard about issues to update Xcode. Maybe try to delete the old installation before installing the new one: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835

Comment: the solution was to totally uninstall XCode from the Application folder. There wasn t any other option. After that downloading xcode from the App Store solved the problem. But this was really frustrating ...

Comment: You do realize that I fixed your post yesterday regarding the capitalization of _Xcode_, yet your send me a comment where you wrote it incorrectly? Even your screenshot is showing it as _Xcode_ ;)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any solution to fix this issue, so the only way was to move Xcode to the trash and then download the whole again...